# Deploying Angular2 on IIS without installing WebPackserver

Tags: angular, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I have a Angular2 app which i need to deploy on IIS server. We are looking at bundling the app to reduce the no of calls for resources and also to minify the app for reducing it's size.
 I have read few articles on webpack tool and they suggest that app can be reduced but there is no physical bundle published to disk by webpack. Rather bundle is streamed in memory and is injected into html at runtime. Webpack server is recommended for this purpose, however i have limitation of hosting app only on IIS.
 So is webpack unsuited for this and do i need to bundle using grunt? I have searched online several times but there is no definitive answer.Plz Share your thoughts.

Comment: I use Webpack to build my site and it creates all the bundle files etc. right on disk. I just copy them over to my webserver and everything works. I think maybe you just need to look at Webpack config options for production builds and output? 

For example, say you use the CLI to generate your angular 2 project. You build out all the physical files just by typing "ng build -prod". This also does the minification and everything else. The CLI uses webpack, so it most definitely can write files to disk.

Comment: Check this out: btw, if you mean the "webpack dev server", they tell you right away, don't use that in production:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

Comment: @TimConsolazio : Thanks , I'll give it a try